# Stacked Area Line Chart with Overlapping Values

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm trying to create an attendance chart. Previously, there was only 1 time slot, so I used a line chart. However, now there are 2 time slots. So, I'd like to do a stacked area line chart to summarize both individual and total attendance between both time slots. The problem is that some attend both time slots. I don't want the total attendance for the day to be skewed (i.e. total number of people in attendance), nor do I want the attendance for each time slot to be skewed.

How can I track the attendance accurately and represent it on the chart? Is there some way I can specify an "overlap" in attendance (i.e. 100 at time 1, 100 at time 2, 25 at both, for a total of 175 for the day)? Here is an example of one day of data:

[image: Attendance Summary for 04/18/2021]

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste in a few pictures and./or sample data? It is not quite clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Could you provide a sample about this problem? It will be more helpful.

Comment: @Mobus & Lee are you wanting a picture of a stacked area line chart? https://datavizcatalogue.com/methods/stacked_area_graph.html

Comment: Nope. Of your ow  data or at least anonymized version of your data. You can press alt print screen to take a screenshot of your spreadsheet then edit your question and press ctrl V to paste the screenshot directly into your question.

Comment: @MichaelYaeger ,, please [edit] your post & share the data you have used to create the Chart & fining problem , will help us to reproduce the chart to fix it !!

Comment: I added an example of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you want to plot attendance vs date, which wasn't clear.

Set up data as shown, with dates in the first column, then attendance in the first time slot only, attendance in the second time slot only, then attendance in both time slots.

Make a chart of this data. I show a stacked area chart, but I prefer the stacked column chart.

[image: Attendance by Time Slot: Data and Charts]

EDIT:

Here's how to do an overlap with Area Charts. Arrange the data as shown, with total for each time slot, and in between the negative of the number of people common to both. Make your area chart. Format 9:00 AM as blue, but with 50% transparency. Format 9 & 11 as no fill. Format 11:00 AM as orange with 50% transparency.

Since the 9 & 11 series is negative, it moves down from the previous (9:00 blue) series, and the next series (11:00 orange) starts from the lower position. Where there is no overlap, the orange just seems to start at the top of the blue. And you can use your own colors that might show the overlap more clearly.

[image: Attendance by Time Slot: Data and Area Chart with Overlap]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Attendance is "tracked" over time; that's a given. Day=Daily= Date. I'm not sure how I could have made that more clear, but sorry for the confusion. Also, this chart is not what I'm wanting. I want 9a totals charted + 11a totals charted, but total summary for the day to not include duplicates. If you put the 9+11 column before the 11 only column, it would almost be right, but you would still have to manually sum the "only" and "&" columns to get the correct numbers. I'm trying to do an "overlap", almost like a starting disadvantage for the 11a side of the chart.

Comment: See my addition, after "EDIT".

Comment: this looks exactly like what I'm looking for. I'm going to try it out and let you know if it works. Thanks!

Comment: I think putting the overlapping region in the middle makes loads of sense, visually, so you can intuitively include with either of the other area - a bit like the overlapping region of an Euler / Venn diagram.
I agree that stacked columns is clearer than an area chart for all the usual reasons, including focussing on heights (values) rather than slopes (rates of change).

Comment: @MichaelYaeger - did it work? Will you mark Jon's reply as the answer if it did?

Comment: It took me a while to get this setup properly, but it did the trick. Thanks!